# Duplicating a linked list without using recursion

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I'm trying to figure out how to duplicate a linked list, and after debugging on Vs code I'm getting a segmentation fault on `cuurent->data = temp->data;`
and I'm not sure why this is happening.

and this is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};
struct node* head;
struct node* head2;

struct node* Insert(struct node* head, int x)
{
    struct node* temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = head;
    return temp;
}

void Print(struct node* head)
{
    struct node* tmp1 = head;
    printf("List is:");
    while (tmp1 != NULL) {
        printf(" %d", tmp1->data);
        tmp1 = tmp1->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

struct node* dupe(struct node* head, struct node* head2)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return NULL;
    struct node* temp = head;
    struct node* prev = NULL;
    struct node* cuurent = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    cuurent->data = temp->data;
    if (head2 == NULL) {
        cuurent->next = head2;
        head2 = cuurent;
    }
    while (temp != NULL) {
        temp = temp->next;
        cuurent = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        cuurent->data = temp->data;
        cuurent->next = prev;
        prev = cuurent;
    }
    return head2;
}

int main(void)
{
    head = NULL;
    head2 = NULL;
    head = Insert(head, 4);
    head = Insert(head, 2);
    head = Insert(head, 3);
    head = Insert(head, 5);
    head2 = dupe(head, head2);
    Print(head);
    Print(head2);
}
```

Comment: You move `temp = temp->next;` and no longer check if `temp` is a null pointer before `cuurent->data = temp->data;` - your logic is flawed here

Comment: Didn't inspect your code, but could be an un-initialized or NULL pointer. It's helpful if you include the traceback, you might even see the answer yourself. Also, worth mentioning your compiler and platform, for potential tips.

Comment: I don't understand what the role of `head2` is supposed to be in this code, either in `main` or in your `dupe` function. Regarding replicating a linked list without recursion, a simple forward-chaining loop should be pretty simple, and only require about 8 lines of function code.

Comment: So doing this with recursion would not be a problem for you?

Comment: I recommend to use more different identifieres. The compiler might not have a problem with a global variable and several parameters of the same name. But I don't trust myself with that kind of devious detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments,

```
while (temp != NULL) {
    temp = temp->next;
```

changes the value of `temp` immediately *after* guarding against a null pointer value.

This eventually means

```
cuurent->data = temp->data;
```

will cause [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) by dereferencing `temp` when it is the null pointer value.

---

You can apply the exact same looping principles shown in `Print` to copy the list. The only difference being you must save a pointer to the first node.

The same principle can be used again when it comes time to [`free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) the memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *insert(struct node *next, int x)
{
    struct node *n = malloc(sizeof *n);

    n->data = x;
    n->next = next;

    return n;
}

void print_list(struct node *head)
{
    printf("List is: ");

    while (head) {
        printf("%d ", head->data);
        head = head->next;
    }

    printf("\n");
}

void free_list(struct node *head)
{
    struct node *t;

    while (head) {
        t = head->next;
        free(head);
        head = t;
    }
}

struct node *copy_list(struct node *head)
{
    struct node *root = NULL;

    for (struct node *current; head; head = head->next) {
        struct node *new = insert(NULL, head->data);

        if (!root)
            root = new;
        else
            current->next = new;

        current = new;
    }

    return root;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct node *head = NULL;
    head = insert(head, 4);
    head = insert(head, 2);
    head = insert(head, 3);
    head = insert(head, 5);

    struct node *head2 = copy_list(head);

    print_list(head);
    print_list(head2);

    free_list(head);
    free_list(head2);
}
```

Output:

```
List is: 5 3 2 4 
List is: 5 3 2 4
```